# How to write JavaScript prototype chain

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

How to create an object of Manager with name "joe" and create subordinate "John" and add Salary to John.

Ex. var result = new Manager("Joe").getSubordinate("John").addSalary(10000);

```
function Manager(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.getSubordinate = function(submane){

        return submane;
    }
}
var result = new Manager('Joe');
```

I am able to write down so far.

Comment: Is this a caption contest? There's no question… see [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: "prototype chain"? from your code you seem to be asking how to write a fluent api...

Comment: use promise to chain. Or use http://ramdajs.com/

Comment: `Objective of the code` yep, that code will do exactly that ... once you've written the Manager object correctly

Comment: @JaromandaX ok got it.

Comment: What is `result`? And what part are you stuck on implementing?

Comment: @4castle addSalary I am not able to implement

Comment: show what you are able to implement, so far you've implemented nothing

Comment: function Manager(name){
 this.name = name;
 this.getSubordinate = function(submane){
  
  return submane;
 }
}
var result = new Manager('Joe');


@JaromandaX I have implement thjis much

Comment: put it in the question, you can't read code in a comment!

Comment: `function(submane){ return submane; }` - why do you need a function that returns the argument you passed into the function

Comment: That exactly my question. I don't know the right way to writing this code. Could you please able to help me. I am learning OOJS. So I don't have a good idea about creating prototype chain like this. @JaromandaX

Comment: So, something like https://jsfiddle.net/ps5Lahj0/

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to chain the functions you need to return the objects like if you have a class Manager and one of Ordinate:

```
function Manager(name){
    this.name = name;

    this.subordinate = {John : new Subordinate('John')};

    this.getSubordinate = function getSubordinate(subName){
        return this.subordinate[subName];
    };
}

function Subordinate(name){
    this.name = name;

    this.salary = 0;

    this.addSalary = function addSalary(salary){
        this.salary = salary;
        return salary;
    };
}

var result = new Manager('Joe').getSubordinate("John").addSalary(10000);
```

but i think you want as a result a Manager object so I recomend to use this way

```
function Manager(name){
    var self = this;

    this.name = name;

    this.subordinate = {John : new Subordinate('John')};

    this.getSubordinate = function getSubordinate(subName){
        return this.subordinate[subName];
    };

    this.addSalaryToSubordinate = function addSalaryToSubordinate(subName, salary){
        self.getSubordinate(subName).addSalary(salary);
        return self;
    };
}

function Subordinate(name){
    this.name = name;

    this.salary = 0;

    this.addSalary = function addSalary(salary){
        this.salary = salary;
        return salary;
    };
}

var result = new Manager('Joe').addSalaryToSubordinate ("John", 10000);
```